# GET request for xsl works in Firefox/Opera/GoogleChrome/Safari/ and even IE9, but not in IE 8 or IE10

Tags: javascript, xslt, html, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to populate a div through JS/XSLT in a GET request.  See code below:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
    function displayResult()
    {
    xml=loadXMLDoc("Folder/data.xml");
    xsl=loadXMLDoc("Folder/data.xsl");
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
      ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
      document.getElementById("reps").innerHTML=ex;
      }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
      xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
      document.getElementById("reps").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }
```

This works fine in Firefox/Opera/Chrome/Safari/IE9  but not in IExplorer 8&10

When I checked how it was being displayed in Explorer 8 & 10, it ignores the code completely, as if it wasn't there, like so: `<div id="reps" /></div>` but in all other browswers the entire list/table is populated inside this div just fine

Now, when I check just the xslt by itself in Explorer, it works fine and the list is there.  So it just seems to be a problem with this JS pulling it into the div in IE/S

Any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: The most likely very vital `loadXMLDoc()` implementation is missing from your code listing.

Comment: You should also tell us which IE version you have tested with and you want to target with your code.

Comment: Martin - I've tried this on IE8 and IE10  
JLRishe - do you mean this : 'function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}'  
That is already in the code as well

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with IE 8 and IE 10? With IE 10 it is known that the `responseXML` returned by default by `XMLHttpRequest` is no longer an MSXML DOM document but rather an IE DOM document and for the latter `transformNode` is not supported. So with IE 10 I would expect an error on the attempt to call `xml.transformNode`. To fix that problem with IE 10 you either need to make sure you use `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0')` instead of `new XMLHttpRequest()` or I think you can set `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); try { xhttp.responseType = 'msxml-document'; } catch(e){}`.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it works in ALL browsers once I publish to web, but not in IE8 or IE10 ...it worked in IE9 for some strange reason, and I haven't tried an earlier version.  So now I am really confused!